# Pass parameters to C # file using .bat

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have a ready-made application written in C # that takes .hex files from my computer to record on an electronic board.
It does this by receiving by **PARAMETER** the **path** (C: \ ...) of the .hex file to be recorded and the **communication port** (COM) where the device is connected.

What I need to do is:

- Create another file in the .bat extension to run this application using command lines, sending as a parameter the information it needs (file path and communication port).
- What I've tried to do so far is (in .bat):

  ```
    @echo off
    @echo Go to the file location

    cd C:\Users\stephani.ferreira\Desktop\S028-Software-Bootloader_Inclinomoto\S028\Bootloader\bin\Release

    timeout 10

    @echo opens the executable file for the recording application
    .\Bootloader

    PAUSE
  ```

For example, I need the application to write a file from the **C:\Users\AppData\Test** folder to the device that is connected to the **COM2** port.

Is there any way I can pass these parameters to the application through the .Bat file?

Comment: bat syntax is something like `call appname.exe arg1 arg2 argN`

Comment: My ready-made application is not the problem. I don't want to change anything about it because everything is fine. The variable that will store the port name is a SerialPort and the one that will store the path is a string.